# Determine if two fds are duplicates?

Tags: linux, unix, file-descriptor

Preferably portably, but at least under Linux, is there a way to determine if two file descriptors are duplicates referring to the same open file description?

Comment: There is a big difference between refering to the same file (opened twice the same file, via same or different names) and to the same file descriptor (created with [`dup`(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup)). I suppose you mean the later, but the title looks more like you mean the former.

Comment: @Jan, right. Edited for clarity.

Comment: You mean, other than `lseek()`ing on a fd and seeing if the position has changed in the other fd?

Comment: @ninjalj, yes.  As I'm sure you know, that's both heavy-handed (alters the state of a resource) and not always feasible (ESPIPE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux 5.12, you can use the [kcmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kcmp.2.html) syscall with `KCMP_FILE` to determine if two file descriptors refer to the same open file description.